gitlab ci/cd for automatically increase android app version
We need to write gitlab CI/CD to automatically increase the android app version in major.minor.patch.
We are using flutter to build & to deploy we are using fastlane.
Below is my current CI/CD:-
stages:

build-aab
upload-playstore

build-android:
stage: build-aab
tags:
- mobile
script:
- flutter pub get
- flutter build appbundle
artifacts:
paths:
- build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab
expire_in: 30 day
only:
- test
upload-to-playstore:
stage: upload-playstore
tags:
- mobile
script:
- ls -lart
- export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
- export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
- cd android
- fastlane deploy_beta
only:
- test
We have try find the way to automate version increase but not able to find a way.
